# Problems compiling code written in old version in new R version

Tags: r, compiler-errors, version

I am having trouble running commands in new version of R (4.0.1; Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)) and RStudio (Version 1.3.959) which worked well in the older version of R.

Let's say, I have a table named Check with more than 10,000 rows and more than 100 variables (categorical and numeric).

If I try to invoke the droplevels command, I get the below message.

```
Check <- droplevels(Check)
Error in .shallow(x, cols = cols, retain.key = TRUE) : 
can't set ALTREP truelength
```

However, the below works

```
Check <- rapply(Check, f = droplevels, classes = "factor", how = "replace")
```

When I try to replace the NA's in a categorical variable by defining a new level and replacing it for NA's, I get the below message:

```
levels(Check$A) <- c(levels(Check$A), 'unknown.')
# Check$A <- factor(Check$A, levels=c(levels(Check$A), 'unknown.'))
Check$A[is.na(Check$A)] <- 'unknown.'
Error in setalloccol(newx) : can't set ALTREP truelength
```

When I try to open the table, I get the below message:

```
View(Check)
Error in view: can't set ALTREP truelength
```

I do not understand what has seriously gone wrong here. Any idea please?

I tried playing with

```
library(tidyverse)
Check <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, letters[1:10]), col2 = c(NA, NA, 1:8, NA), 
                 col3 = c(NA, letters[1:5], NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
Test <- Check
Test <- droplevels(Test)
str(Test)
Test2 <- Test[6:11,]
Test2 <- Test2 %>% mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.character), as.factor)
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
```

The above works fine and using `dput(Test2)` yields

```
structure(list(col1 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), col2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, NA), col3 = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"unknown."), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, for my data, I get something like this in the end using dput, though I am not using data.table.

```
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000004f81ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I am trying to imitate my data and shall pose it, when I am successful in doing it asap.

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible, since we don't have `Check`.  Try to reduce it to a more reasonable size that still illustrates the error, then use `dput(Check)` to include it in your question.   You should also put in calls to `library()` for each of the packages you're using.

Comment: @user2554330: Thanks for your response. I have edited my question. I will pose the "Check" as soon as I can imitate it successfully.

Comment: Since the error occurs on a `data.table` object but appears to be very low level, maybe it's as simple as updating your packages (including `data.table`) so they are compatible with your current R version.

Comment: I have installed R 4.0.2 (from R 4.0.1) now and downloaded all the packages completely and dependencies. It seems to work now, however, I came across the same trouble again. Closed everything and made it run again. And, strangely it works without any trouble. Still do not understand where the trouble was/is.

Comment: Even if data.table package is not loaded, do data frames convert themselves to data.table? Since I get "class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))" in dput when I check. However, if I force convert the data, say x, to a data frame as x <- data.frame(x), then the problem of Error in setalloccol(newx) : can't set ALTREP truelength does'nt come. What do data.table and ALTREP actually do in the background?

Comment: No, data frames don't do anything on their own.  If the class includes `"data.table"`, it's because some function put that there.  Check the class before and after every function call and you'll find the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

The below example runs fine without any problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

Check <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, letters[1:10]), col2 = c(NA, NA, 1:8, NA), 
                    col3 = c(NA, letters[1:5], NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
Test1 <- Check
dput(Test1)

Test2 <- as.data.table(Check) # Convert to data.table
dput(Test2)


Test1 <- droplevels(Test1)
str(Test1)
Test1 <- Test1 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test1, is.character), as.factor)
Test1 <- Test1 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test1, is.integer), as.numeric)
str(Test1)
Test1 <- droplevels(Test1)

Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
str(Test2)
Test2 <- Test2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.character), as.factor)
Test2 <- Test2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.integer), as.numeric)
str(Test2)
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
```

Now consider this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

Check1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, letters[1:200]), col2 = c(NA, NA, 1:198, NA), 
                 col3 = c(NA, letters[1:195], NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 col4 = c(NA, NA, letters[1:199]), col5 = c(NA, letters[7:206]),
                 col6 = c(NA, NA, letters[1:198], NA),
                 col7 = c(NA, letters[1:197], NA, NA, NA),
                 col8 = c(NA, letters[4:203]),
                 col9 = c(NA, letters[6:205]),
                 col10 = c(letters[1:200], NA),
                 col11 = c(NA, NA, letters[1:197], NA, NA),
                 col12 = c(NA, letters[2:201]),
                 col13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, letters[1:196]) )

Check2 <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:1000,201,rep=TRUE)))

Check <- cbind(Check1, Check2)


Test1 <- Check
dput(Test1) 
# dput gives ,row.names = c(NA, -201L), class = "data.frame")

Test2 <- as.data.table(Check)
dput(Test2)
# dput gives row.names = c(NA, -201L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000052e1ef0>, class # = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

# The below block runs without any problem since Test1 is of class data.frame
Test1 <- droplevels(Test1)
str(Test1)
Test1 <- Test1 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test1, is.character), as.factor)
Test1 <- droplevels(Test1)
Test1 <- Test1 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test1, is.integer), as.numeric)
str(Test1)
Test1 <- droplevels(Test1)

# The below block gives problem since Test2 is of class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
str(Test2)
Test2 <- Test2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.character), as.factor)
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
Test2 <- Test2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.integer), as.numeric)
str(Test2)
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
```

I get the following error message running the first 4 lines:

```
Error in in .shallow(x, cols = cols, retain.key = TRUE) : can't set ALTREP truelength
```

If I try to open Test2 data frame, I get the following message

```
View(Test2)
Error in View : can't set ALTREP truelength
```

If I, however, delete Test2 using

```
rm(Test2)
```

and run the following, I do not get any error:

```
Test2 <- as.data.frame(Test2)
str(Test2)
Test2 <- Test2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.character), as.factor)
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
Test2 <- Test2 %>% dplyr::mutate_if(sapply(Test2, is.integer), as.numeric)
str(Test2)
Test2 <- droplevels(Test2)
```

1. Does size restriction play a role in data.table, since it seems to works for small data and hesitates for the example above.
2. Does it mean each time it must be ensured that the data is saved as a data frame with class = "data.frame"?
3. When do such data frames get converted automatically to data.table, because in my real data set though data.table library is not loaded, despite which, the data is saved as a data.table?

Any explanation please? I have R 4.0.2 and swiped the space clean and reinstalled all packages and dependencies fresh, and RStudio version is 1.3.959 .

Comment: Great reproducible. Try using reprex() and post this as an issue to get the right attention: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues